# calculate time complexity in recursive and dynamic solution of “number of ways to move from top left to bottom right in a matrix”

Tags: recursion, data-structures, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

There is a `m*n` matrix and we need to find all possible paths from top left to bottom right.
It can be traversed only in right and down directions.

I have the following doubts:

1. In recursive approach I understand that the time complexity will be O(2<sup>(m+n)</sup>). How can I get it using induction?
2. How do I find the complexity in case of dynamic programming solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In dynamic programming you try to fill the array **dp[i][j]** where **dp[i][j]** means number of ways to reach cell (i,j) from top left cell. Also **dp[i][j]=dp[i][j-1]+dp[i-1][j]** , ( avoiding the corner case where i=1 or j=1). So in total you have to fill the dp table with **n*m** entries and each entry depends on constant number of entries ( at max 2 )  **dp[i-1][j]** and **dp[i][j-1]**. Thus complexity will be O(2*n * m) which is **O(n*m)**.

Secondly,if we dont do dp or memoization ( can goole it ) and do it recursively then you are basically tracing all the possible paths while finding the count. So complexity would be number of paths from top left cell to bottom right. All paths will have **m-1** horizontal and **n-1** vertical moves.So number of paths becomes  **(m+n-2)!  /  ( (m-1)! * (n-1)! )**. Which is the complexity, not exponential as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question without memoisation:

> 1) In recursive approach I understand that the time complexity will be
>   O(2(m+n)). How can I get it using induction?

when we represent the successive calls of the recursive function in a binary tree, at each floor `k` representing the `k`<sup>th</sup> move — `0` standing for the root of the binary tree, the start position — the function makes two new recursive calls at the `k + 1`<sup>th</sup> floor. Besides, as stated in [sachas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27552407/calculate-time-complexity-in-recursive-and-dynamic-solution-of-number-of-ways-t/27576142#27576142), all paths will have `m-1` horizontal and `n-1` vertical moves. There are therefore `(m-1)(n-1)` floors, one for each possible `k`<sup>th</sup> move.

Then, because:

- there are 2<sup>k</sup> calls per floor,
- calls at every floor add up,
- there is a total of `(m-1)(n-1)` floors,

there are therefore 2<sup>0</sup> + 2<sup>0</sup> + ... + 2<sup>(m - 1)(n - 1)</sup> = 2<sup>(m - 1)(n - 1) + 1</sup> - 1 calls of the function (according to the formula of a sum of a geometric sequence), and the recursive function having a time complexity of **O(1)**, the complexity is then **O(2<sup>(m - 1)(n - 1) + 1</sup>)** = **O(2<sup>mn</sup>)**. Hence the result.